# RxJS: Second observable's input argument depends on first observable's output

Tags: rxjs

I have two observables

```
baseObs$ = serviceCall(); // this return Observable<Foo>
secondObs$ = serviceCall(args); // this return Observable<Bar>
```

args in this example is public variable defined somewhere else. It doesn't need to be though if that makes this easier.

baseObs I can call whenever I want, but secondObs I can only call after baseObs is succesfully called and handled (don't know the right words so example follows):

I have now something like

```
baseObs$.subscribe(x => {
  const args = x.args; // just example. Point is, I need x to build args.
  serviceCall(args).subscribe(y => {
    console.log(y); // This is fine
  });
});
```

This suits my needs but I got feedback that no subscribe should live inside another subscribe. How would you achieve same thing using baseObs$ and secondObs$ defined above?

PS. All is pseudo code but hopefully I didn't do too much typos. I think the idea should be clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case that the first observable only emits once (like a typical HTTP request), any one of `switchMap`, `mergeMap` etc. will do:

```js
serviceCall().pipe(
  switchMap(x => serviceCall(x.args))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

If that assumption is *not* true, you're going to want to read their respective documentation to understand how behavior will change between them. In fact, I'd recommend reading up on them to know their differences even just in general, as it's very valuable information when dealing with reactive code.

Comment: This is what I needed. Your assumption was correct too!